# Randomly generating lake for 2d tile game

Tags: java, dictionary, 2d, tile

I have a question regarding randomly generated lake in a 2d tile based game. I use a two-dimensional int which holds the value of the tiles. Each value represents an image (16x16 square of E.G grass).

So I came up this method which is probably already known here but I use a 'frog'. The frog jumps around creating source blocks. Each source block cant be more than 2-4 tiles away from other source blocks. Then, a specific figure is drawn around the source:

```
        map[startX][startY] = tile;
        map[startX-1][startY] = tile;
        map[startX-2][startY] = tile;
        map[startX+1][startY] = tile;
        map[startX+2][startY] = tile;
        map[startX][startY-1] = tile;
        map[startX][startY-2] = tile;
        map[startX][startY+1] = tile;
        map[startX][startY+2] = tile;
        map[startX+1][startY+1] = tile;
        map[startX-1][startY+1] = tile;
        map[startX+1][startY-1] = tile;
        map[startX-1][startY-1] = tile;
```

The startX,startY being coordinates around which the figure is drawn.
This is all hard coded of course. I was wondering, is there any algorithm or method to do this automatically? You would give the size of the figure (this one is set to 2) and it would do it for ya.

Heres the figure: http://tinypic.com/r/2mcu1ol/5

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
int size=2;

for(int i=0;i<=size;i++)
{
    for(int j=i-size;j<=size-i;j++)
    {
        map[startX+i][startY+j]=tile;
        map[startX-i][startY+j]=tile;
    }
}
```